# PHP How to SEND Json

Tags: php, javascript, json

The only way to send a JSON object is via JavaScript?

I'm developing a system that will have a lot of requests, send and receive Json.

If I can only work with Javascript to send the object, how do I trigger the js function?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]

I have a C# working with database.
WCF making the communication between C# and PHP.
I was making the communication with WCF via SOAP, it was working fine but my boss want me to use JSON instead.
I've read some articles about JSON+PHP and the only way to send the JSON object is with JavaScript?

Comment: If you are deving this system, shouldnt you know how to do it? have you started? what have you done so far?

Comment: First start: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+json which gives you http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: Send from where to where? You can use PHP to make requests to others servers (with JSON data in it), but in client-side, you can only use javascript to perform actions

Comment: I was using SOAP but now I have to use Json, never worked with Json, made some search and found only examples using JAvascript, I just want to know if that is the ONLY WAY.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have your JSON string encoded with `json_encode()` you simply `echo` it out with the correct MIME header.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($your_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

to get the php file to return JSON you just make an array of the conditions and then json_encode echo it.....

response.php

```
$cond ? $response= array("conditions" => true) : $response = array("conditions"=>false);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mazlix but the problem is how to send the JSON object.

Comment: Before PHP 5.2, you can use the [JSON PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/json).